# How can I limit the number of records inserted on an INSERT INTO at one time

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I want to do an insert into my database like this.  But the Table's may have 200k+ records in them.  I want to split up the inserts into groups of 10,000 or so, how can I do this efficiently in MySQL only?

```
INSERT INTO `slugs` (`sku`, `tablename`)
select `SKU`, 'tableA'
from `tableA`
WHERE `SKU` NOT IN
(select `sku` from `slugs` where `tablename` = 'tableA');
```

Example Code:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a75a1/8

Comment: Why do you want to split up the inserts?

Comment: It's going very slow, and I was told if I split it up it into multiple transactions it would probably speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `LIMIT 10000` to the end and run it until rows inserted = 0.

If it is not a one shot, you can do this in a procedure with a loop..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET @rank=0;
select rank
, IF(MOD(rank,10000)=0,CONCAT(IF(MOD(rank,10000)=1,CONCAT("insert ignore into table values (""",NAME,""",""",SKU,""")"),CONCAT(",(""",NAME,""",""",SKU,""")")),";"),IF(MOD(rank,10000)=1,CONCAT("insert ignore into table values (""",NAME,""",""",SKU,""")"),CONCAT(",(""",NAME,""",""",SKU,""")"))) as insert_statement
from (
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,NAME,SKU
from tablea 
) der
```